# How to put vector into function's argument?

Tags: matlab

I would like to know how to put a vector into function's argument. Let the user enters a vector `x=[x1 x2]` and the coefficients `a, b`. And our task would be for example to plot a graph of a linear function `a*x+b`, where `x=[x1 x2]`. I thought that the beginning might look like this:

```
function L = linear([x1 x2], a, b) 
  .... 
  y = [x1 x2] * a + b 
  plot ([x1 x2], y)
```

Unfortunately, it is all wrong. Matlab still reports ERROR. Help. Thanks

Comment: This error was easy to see, but for future questions it is helpful to know what your ERROR actually said.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Matlab does not allow you to specify two variables for a single input. There are two options here. First, you can assign x1 and x2 as separated arguments:

`function L = linear(x1,x2,a,b)`

Second, you can keep as a single input and index out your two variables:

```
function L = linear(x,a,b)
x1 = x(1);
x2 = x(2);
```

Another note - in the code you show, you only ever use `[x1 x2]` and never separate them out. You don't really even need to define `x1` and `x2` like I did in option 2 above. The confusion may be because you have them defined separately in your calling function. In that case you could *call* the function (not define) as you originally described: `linear([x1 x2],a,b);`